# How to generate Localizable.strings file from strings.xml in Android

Tags: android, string, localization, localizable.strings

I want the strings in strings.xml to be converted to ios Localizable.strings format

Format:

```
"String"="String"
```

I have used few online tools in web which converts xml to localible.strings, but the format I have seen is :

```
 "Key"="Value"
```

But I need in this format:

```
 "value"="value"
```

example:
     if this is the Strings.xml file,

```
    <resources>
    <String name="addtocart">Please add to cart</string>
    </resources>
```

The localizable.strings format should be in :

```
   "Please add to cart"="Please add to cart" (I need this)
```

and not

```
   "addtocart"="Please add to cart" (Format resulted from conversion tools in web)
```

Is there any plugin or built in functionality in eclipse. I am new to android and this localization process.

Can one help me out in achieving this please...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A pretty simple `awk` bash script can do your job.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    FS = "^ *<string *| *>|<\/string> *$|^ *<!-- *| *--> *$";
}
{
    if (/<string.*name\=\".*\".*>.*<\/string> *$/){
        print "\""$3 "\" \= \"" $3 "\";"
    }
    else if(/<!--.*-->/)
        print "// "$2;
    else if(/^ *$/)
        print ""
}'
```

Save the above to `android2ios.sh`. This script will read from the standard input stream.

For example your Android strings content like `<string name="addtocart">Please add to cart</string>` is copied to your clipboard, and you're using OS X as your operating system.

```
 pbpaste | sh  android2ios.sh
```

This will print

```
"Please add to cart" = "Please add to cart";
```

You can do the redirect and pipe thing in your own way. The script only does the converting.

Comments like `<!--comment-->` and multiline content are also handled well by this script.

BTW, I like the `"addtocart"="Please add to cart"` way better, because `"value" = "value"` may result in duplicated keys.

Comment: `<string name="text_register">REGISTER</string>` becomes `"REGISTER" = "REGISTER";`, it should be `"text_register" = "REGISTER"` So I have changed `print "\""$3 "\" \= \"" $3 "\";"` to `print "\""$2 "\" \= \"" $3 "\";"` then it becomes `"name="text_register"" = "REGISTER"` then I have replaced `"name="` to "" and `"" = ` to `" =`